# Command not parsed properly in ESP8266 SMING example

Tags: esp8266, sming

I have set up the UART to receive and process commands using the CommandProcessing library by using the Telnet_TCPServer_TCPClient example of the SMING framework.

Here are the relevant code;

```
void init()
{
    Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD_RATE); 
    Serial.commandProcessing(true);
    commandHandler.registerCommand(CommandDelegate("appheap","Usage appheap on/off/now for heapdisplay\r\n","testGroup", appheapCommand));
    memoryTimer.initializeMs(250,checkHeap).start();
}

void appheapCommand(String commandLine  ,CommandOutput* commandOutput)
{
    Vector<String> commandToken;
    int numToken = splitString(commandLine, ',' , commandToken);
        //The rest are same as inside sample code.
}
```

When I send this string `appheap ,off` to the UART, the command is parsed properly.

However, when I send this string `appheap,off` to the UART, the command is not parsed properly. The message returned is `Command not found, cmd = 'appheap,off'`.

If things are going fine, both strings `appheap ,off` and `appheap,off`should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Command Processing library cannot detect the command with a comma. It detects the command with a space. You create a command list with `CommandDelegate("command_name","Usage", ...)`.

In your context, `appheap,off` does not have a space, so you get a message `Command not found, cmd = 'appheap,off'`. The correct way to call the command is `appheap off`.